# TableOperation.Insert always returns Conflict 409, TableOperation.InsertOrReplace succeeds

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azurite

The issue only relates to azurite as using an actual Azure table works fine. I noticed searching in azurite doesn't return ETag for any entity.

Using the below entity, `TableOperation.Insert` always succeeds but always returns `Conflict` `409`, even though the new entity was added to the table.

`TableOperation.InsertOrReplace` always succeeds and doesn't throw an exception.

There are no duplicates in the table so there's no obvious reason why `Insert` should fail and `InsertOrReplace` should succeed. Is there any reason why `Insert` would succeed and fail at the same time?

```
public class MessageQEntity : TableEntity
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public MessageQEntity()
    {
        PartitionKey = "Region";
        RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept is very simple. `Conflict` always arises when you are trying to insert a new entity but there's already an entity in the table with the same `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`.

In your case, as you did not show me the code, you should be reusing the same object of `MessageQEntity` to insert new entities by updating `Message` and/or `Status` fields, but not `RowKey`.

It's straightforward why `InsertOrReplace` works as expected, as it understands there's an existing entity and so, it replaces that entity with the newly added entity :)

Comment: thanks for that but the table is empty. I used powershell to delete the table, create a new one, then TableOperation.Insert and it raises the conflict. It doesn't occur on actual storage tables in Azure, only on azurite tables.

Comment: Can you make sure Azurite supports Table Insert operation? I think it is still in their pipeline as Azurite mostly supports Blob and storage queue services and partially Tables.

Comment: yes it's Azurite V2 as V3 doesn't fully support tables yet